# Why does a $ in the replacement string passed to the replace() function break some of the time?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable that I'm using to build a JavaScript function call, and JavaScript's `.replace()` to surround the line of text with a span and onclick event.  The `.replace()` portion looks like this:

```
code.replace(/(\d{4}\s+)?(LOCAL|PARAMETER|GLOBAL)\s+USING\s+([\S]+)/g, 
   "<span class=\"natprint_popup\" onclick=\"getNaturalCode('" 
     + lib 
     + "','$3','@#test_prod_qual|',0,'Y'); return false;\">$&</span>");
```

The only problem is that the variable `lib` contains a `$` at the end some of the time; for example, `lib == DPDRI$`.  This causes the JavaScript on my page to break and I get output that breaks at the end of `lib` and displays the rest of the Javascript function parameters as plain text:

```
,'DPDPDRNO','TEST',0,'Y'); return false;">
```

I've been looking fruitlessly for answers for a few days now.  I've tried doing `lib.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");` and the `\$` is successfully making its way into the variable but it still breaks my code.  It seems like the JavaScript engine is trying to interpret the `$` at the end of `lib` as a captured match and it's making it blow up.  Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Specifying a string as a parameter section](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) of the [`replace()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) on MDC:

> The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns:
>
> ```
> Pattern    Inserts
> $$    Inserts a "$".
> ...
> $'    Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
> ...
> ```

Note that since the contents of your variable is being inserted as a single-quote-wrapped parameter to the function you're calling from onclick, it will *always* be followed by a ' - so when it ends with a $, you'll have inadvertently created a replacement pattern:

```
 ... onclick=\"getNaturalCode('DPDRI$' ...
```

Now, you *could* just change how you quote that particular parameter. But to be safe, you should really escape the $ symbol:

```
 + lib.replace(/\$/g, "$$$$")
```

The above modification will convert "DPDRI$" into "DPDRI$$" prior to its insertion into the replacement string, allowing the final replacement to contain a literal $.

Comment: That seemed to solve my problem.  Thanks for the detailed explanation!